# What's the best way to allow people to download multiple files in different folders from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, download

I have a group of 50 files totaling ~10GB that I want to distribute to a small group of people.  The files are located in different folders and I expect the entire set to be downloaded weekly about 10 times, so a weekly total of approximately 100GB.

When people download them, sometimes they report errors like: `Download limit exceeded`.

I work around that issue, I encourage them to login to their Google account. But then the issue becomes, how to download all of these files at once. Mass downloader extensions like [DownThemAll!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downthemall/nljkibfhlpcnanjgbnlnbjecgicbjkge) seem to fail for Google Drive links.

[JDdownloader 2](https://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2) has the best chance but even that requires a proper configuration to work.

How can I, either by a command line tool or other way, allow people to download all of my file links at once?

The links are different for each person and are emailed to them as a list of shared link URLs.

Is this unreasonable? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder for every person. In each folder, put shortcuts to the files they need. You can create a shortcut for an item by right-clicking it, then selecting "Add a shortcut to Drive"; move the shortcut to the individual's folder once you have created the shortcut. Now, share each person's individual folder with them. They can then download that folder, and that action will download the latest version of the original files.